# html icon google

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, favicon

I am trying out icons for the title bar and address bar in the latest html.

I was wondering how to make it compatible with the latest version of IE and Chrome. 
Has anyone run into a similar issue? 
I got it to work on Firefox with:

> link rel="shortcut icon" href="foo.ico" type= "image/x-icon"

Thanks!

Comment: Try Googling for "favicon". There are countless resources for this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Accessibility) this will work in all major browsers:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />
```

You can also name your file `favicon.ico` and it will be displayed automatically. Sometimes it takes a while until your browser refreshes the favicon. Try the private/ incognito mode which ignores the caches.

Also confirm that your browser finds the file by opening it directly.

Comment: Thanks! I renamed it favicon.ico in the root folder and tried the method above. It works fine now.

Comment: Note that using the default location violates some w3c spec or another.  It's better to use the `<link>` tag as well so if you change the icon IE will update.